# Is "Free Worldwide Shipping" misleading?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

Do you think it's misleading for a business to advertise "Free Worldwide Shipping" if:

- The business ships to most but not all countries.
- Free shipping is available for all countries the business ships to.
- The business is not responsible for international customs/duties.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question! I am curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: I would assume "Free Worldwide Shipping" meant they ship worldwide and it's free. Not including customs, import taxes, etc. is expected though. Yes, I would say it was misleading.

Comment: It's certainly misleading if they don't use ships. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, because the meaning of "worldwide" is not very strict. It means "free shipping all around the world" just like I could say "I've travelled all around the world but never once have I been lucky enough to see an aurora."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).